# How to fix Archlinux not recognizing headset michrophone via headphone jack?

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, intel

My audio card: HDA Intel PCH 
My chipset: Realtek ALC887-VD

What I've tried: 
Installing Alsa and Pulseaudio audio drivers. 
Experimenting with the audio drivers.
Looking at several forums (nothing has worked so far). 
I've used two different headsets, one Beats and another one I don't know the name of. Regardless, none worked. \

Comment: Isn't the output muted by some chance?

Comment: @vfbsilva It doesn't show up. The Input field is completely blank & unclickable.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting

Comment: @StephenBoston Alright, We've got the microphone to register, but it won't pick up audio, just static.

Comment: I would suggest to try pipewire instead of pulseaudio. 
For me it did the trick !

Comment: @ebal Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it later today & see if it works out! I honestly didn't think of that. Also sorry for the late respnse, I was super busy. Anyways, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: It seems that I have Pipewire as well. Is there anything else I can do or am I just gonna have to buy a new mic?